# Show that $T\in L(V,V)$ is invertible on $\mathrm{Im}(T^k)$ if $V=\ker(T^k)\oplus\mathrm{Im}(T^k)$

Tags: linear-algebra

So my professor gave me this question.

Let $V$ be a vector space. Let $T:V\to V$ be a linear map and $U_i=\ker T^i$, $W_i=\mathrm{Im}\ T^i$ for all $i\ge0$.

Assuming that for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $V$ is a direct sum of $U_{k}$ and $W_{k}$. I need to prove that $T|_{W_{k}}$ is invertible.

So, I tried to prove that $T|_{W_{k}}$ is bijective and therefore invertible. 
Now I have to prove that
$$U_{k}=U_{k+1}\ \text{ and }\ W_{k}=W_{k+1}.$$
So what I have to do is to prove that

1. $U_{k+1} \subset U_{k}$ and $U_{k} \subset U_{k+1}$,
2. $W_{k+1} \subset W_{k}$ and $W_{k} \subset W_{k+1}$.

Regarding 1, the second part is very easy but what about the first part?

Regarding 2, the first part is very easy but what about the second part?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

$V=\operatorname{Ker}\left(T^k\right)\oplus \operatorname{Im}\left(T^k\right)$

---

$T\left(\operatorname{Im}\left(T^k\right)\right) \subseteq \operatorname{Im}\left(T^k\right)$ so we can define

$F:\begin{array}{ll}\operatorname{Im}\left(T^k\right) \to \operatorname{Im}\left(T^k\right)\\ x \mapsto T(x)\end{array}$

$\operatorname{Ker}\left(F^k\right) = \left\{x\in \operatorname{Im}\left(T^k\right) \mid T^k(x)=0\right\}=\operatorname{Ker}\left(T^k\right) \cap \operatorname{Im}\left(T^k\right)=\{0\}$

$\operatorname{Ker}\left(F\right) \subseteq \operatorname{Ker}\left(F^k\right) = \{0\}$ so $\operatorname{Ker}\left(F\right)=\{0\}$

So $F \in \mathcal{GL}\left(\operatorname{Im}\left(T^k\right)\right)$

Comment: I misread. "So I had to proof that $T|W_k$ is invertible". I read "So I have a proof that..."

Comment: @xavierm02 thank you !! but there is one thing I missing, $W_{i+1}=T(W_{i})$ I understand but why $T(W_{i})=W_{i}$  ?

Comment: @xavierm02 and how can you assume that $(T|_{W{i}})^{i+1}$ is invertible ?

Comment: What is element chasing?

Comment: @BryanUrízar is to proof 2 things are equal by showing that each one is a subset of the other

Comment: @wantToLearn Ah, I didn't know that's how it was called. Thanks.

Comment: @wantToLearn : I edited. I'm not sure what you wanted. So show that it's invertible or to use the fact that it is to show the equality of subspaces?